# Can any soul gems hold a dragon soul?

Tags: video-games, dragons, the-elder-scrolls, skyrim

In the Dawnguard questline, Serana offers to do a partial soul trap on the Dragonborn. But being a dragonborn, he/she has the soul of a dragon. Can a dragon soul be fully contained in a soul gem? Serana managed to trap a portion of the Dragonborn’s soul, but I’m not aware of anyone trying to trap an entire dragon soul.

I assume that dragons have 100% soul-trap resistance, so that casting Soul Trap on one would have no effect. If that’s all it took to trap a dragon soul, someone might have done it when the dragons returned to Skyrim. (Enough city guards could kill a weak dragon, even if you don’t help them.) Still, the Dragonborn apparently does not have soul-trap resistance, since Serana was able to cast a partial soul trap on him.

What happens if someone casts Soul Trap on a dragonborn? Did anyone ever try to soul-trap someone in Tiber Septim’s line, for example?

(From browsing [UESP](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:Enchanting#Enchanting), it seems that enchanting was first practiced in the First Era, while the Dragon War was earlier, in the Merethic Era. So probably no one tried to soul-trap a dragon during the Dragon War, but the resurrected dragons ought to be fair game for soul-trapping, if it’s possible to accomplish.)

Comment: When you kill a dragon and take the soul you use for shouts, isn't that the same one that would normally go into a soul gem? Once get all the words, the souls just pile up. Would think to get a dragon soul into a gem, would have to absorb it, then convert it. Would be a great mod.

Comment: @DanShaffer That does seem like a good idea for a mod. I imagine a dragon soul would make an amazing enchantment.

Comment: Wish I knew how to make mods or had time to learn. Even take it one step further, a quest line to get a DragonGem to hold the soul. Or use a Greybeard heart somehow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> [Azura's Star] is also the most powerful soul gem in the game, being able to hold Vivec and Almalexia souls. –[elderscrolls.wikia; **Morrowind**](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Azura's_Star_%28Morrowind%29)

If [(yes)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K0-jIOYuYwk) you could trap gods in Morrowind, I don't see why you couldn't trap dragons in Skyrim. However to *truly* kill a dragon in order to release its soul, one must either be a dragon or Dragonborn.

> The Firstborn of Akatosh, who had been transported through time by the ancient Nords, was able to resurrect many of his fallen brethren, as **only the dragons and Dragonborn have the power to permanently kill a dragon** by absorbing its soul. –[uesp.net, Lore: Dragons](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:Dragons)

So, there may be capable soul gems but that's not how it works with dragons or their kin. If *you* are capable of vanquishing a dragon, *you* will absorb its soul.

Even if the town guards had the presence of mind to try and soul trap a dragon, it would fail simply because the soul wouldn't be released and (I would assume that) attempting to on a Dragonborn would fail for the same reason.

Comment: I would just expand this slightly by explaining that in-universe, the more powerful the creature, the higher level the soul gem required to capture it is. Azura's Star was unique and the most powerful soul gem in the games.

Comment: Oh, the answer is different now. Well, the souls of Nords go to Sovergarde (at least sometimes), so surely a Nord dragonborn's soul won't remain with his body when he dies. I suspect that the dragonborns are not resurrectable the way that dragons are, so it may be possible to soul-trap a dragonborn. Or what if I, as a dragonborn, try to pass one of my extra dragon souls into a soul gem? I guess only a dragon or dragonborn can take the soul of a dragon, but a powerful enough soul gem could theoretically hold a dragon's soul, if you were able to separate it from the dragon.

Comment: I suppose that getting ahold of a loose dragon soul and figuring out how to transfer it into a soul gem is merely a practical difficulty, and that there is no reason in principle why a sufficiently powerful soul gem wouldn't be able to contain the soul.

Comment: @MolagBal to my knowledge, serana does soul-trap you if you go to the soul cairn without being/becoming a vampire

Comment: @Termatinator Yeah, but only steals a bit of the soul. Still, it's a bit weird it worked...